# Compare tf.string and python string

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

How can I compare a Tensorflow string tensor to a python string type.
I tried something like this

```
if(tf.constant("neg",tf.string) in key):
 a=True
```

key here, is a tf.string. I want to see if 'neg' is in the key tensor.

Comment: Looks like we don't have a TensorFlow op that does this, maybe file feature request for "regex_match"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently you cannot. Please ask this on TF github in issues section.