# creating a label out of a path part in Tensorflow 2.0 without the path being the label name

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently processing medical data in Tensorflow. The problem I have is in regards to attaching labels to the Data.
The structure of my directory is as follows: There is one big folder that contains 3 subfolders for every patient (with 24 patients, so 72 Folders) in those folders is the data.

Now the Problem is that Patients are divided into two groups, group 1 and group 0(Response to treatment, or no response). 
My objective is to train the Model to figure out which group a patient is supposed to be in. 
I am following [This Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_sets_of_files) on how to create a dataset from all these files. 
But in the Example the label is part of the path. This is not possible here (The University does not want to change the structure of the directory)

Here is my example code "functions" is my python script for all functions and settings is a python script that is supposed to create global variables:

settings.json:

Is my json file for all the settings. Yes I have two files named settings, I'm going to rename those at some point. "labels" is a List of the labels for each subfolder. (first three are patient 1, second are the three for patient 2 etc.)

"labels": [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0.....(too long for here)
"datasetpath" is just the path to my data.
settings.py:

```
import functions

def init():
    global settings
    settings = functions.initjson()
    global a

    a = 1
```

functions.py:
    import settings
    import tensorflow as tf

```
def process_path(file_path):
    parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, '/')
    #label = settings.settings["labels"][settings.a]
    label = settings.a #To test if it ticks up at all
    settings.a = settings.a +1
    return tf.io.read_file(file_path), label
```

as you can see

The actual Script:

```
datasetpath = settings.settings["datasetpath"]
file_paths = functions.getfilepaths(datasetpath,verbose=True)
setpath = pathlib.Path(datasetpath)
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(setpath/'*/*'))
labeled_ds = list_ds.map(functions.process_path)
for f in list_ds.take(5):
  print(f.numpy())
for image_raw, label_text in labeled_ds.take(3):
  print(repr(image_raw.numpy()[:100]))
  print()
  print(label_text.numpy())
```

So I cannot just take a part of the path a s a label how they did it. 
I can't compare the Patient name inside the path with a normal List (see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946810/compare-tf-string-and-python-string))
I tried working with a global variable that ticks up and accesses a list, but it does not tick up.
And I'm fresh out of ideas. 
Does anyone have an Idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it myself now.
It's not ideal, but what I did was going through all Paths and comparing them to the "labels" List. 
Here is the function I used.

```
def PD_PET_list():
    datasetpath = settings["Path to PET"]
    labels = settings["labels"]
    #if settings.verbose: print("Path to Dataset for label Creation:",datasetpath)

    setpath = pathlib.Path(datasetpath)  
    #if settings.debug: print(setpath)
    pat = sorted(glob.glob(str(setpath / '*')))
    global pd
    pd = []
    for i in range(len(labels)):
        # print(pat[i])
        # print(labels[i])
        if labels[i] == 1:
            #print(pat[i])
            #print(labels[i])
            parts = tf.strings.split(pat[i], '/')
            pd.append(parts[-1])
```

Afterwards I just checked if the Name of the Folder is within that list (Looping through the list "If x in y" did not work sadly.